# Refactoring if statements for a telegram bot

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring, telegram

I have this method DetermineInline() which sends us an inline keyboard, I want to add some more functionality to it so it would check for different properties and send an inline keyboard with group numbers, I have a queryhandler object that stores the data, how would I refactor it in a way so that I wouldn't have to use if statements. Example code bellow.

```
private InlineKeyboardMarkup DetermineInline()
    {
        if (_queryHandler.Course == "1" && _queryHandler.Specialization == "Marketing")
        {
            InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new(
            new[]
            {
                new[]
                {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("001","001"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("002","002"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("003","003")
                },
            });
            return inlineKeyboardMarkup;
        }
        if(_queryHandler.Course == "1" && _queryHandler.Specialization == "IRM")
        {
            InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new(
            new[]
            {
                new[]
                {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("004","004"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("005","005"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("006","006")
                },
            });
            return inlineKeyboardMarkup;
        }
        if(_queryHandler.Course == "1" && _queryHandler.Specialization == "Logistics")
        {
            InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new(
            new[]
            {
                new[]
                {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("007","007"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("008","008"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("009","009")
                },
            });
            return inlineKeyboardMarkup;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary` collection where the keys will be the specilizations such as `"Marketing"` and the values will be the `"001"`, `"002"` and so on.

This way you can minimize the if statements. However we still need one if statement for the `_queryHandler.Course` query as it is not same as the other specilization queries.

```csharp
private InlineKeyboardMarkup DetermineInline()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, (string, string, string)>();
    dict.Add("Marketing", ("001","002","003"));
    dict.Add("IRM", ("004","005","006"));
    dict.Add("Logistics", ("007","008","009"));
    
    var q = _queryHandler.Specialization;
            
    if (_queryHandler.Course == "1")
    {
        InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new(
        new[]
        {
            new[]
            {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(dict[q].Item1,dict[q].Item1),
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(dict[q].Item2,dict[q].Item2),
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(dict[q].Item3,dict[q].Item3),
            },
        });
        return inlineKeyboardMarkup;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Dictionary Output:

```csharp
Console.WriteLine(dict["Marketing"].Item1); // 001
Console.WriteLine(dict["IRM"].Item3);       // 006
Console.WriteLine(dict["Logistics"].Item2); // 008
```